# svg "use" tag displays an svg icon upside down

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

My designer gave me an svg icon. 
I display this icon in a D3.js tree layout.
To be able to change the colors I embed the icon in a  tag.

The weird thing is that the icon is diplayed upside down (using chrome).
I dont really understand what is going on there.

I must apply a transformation to get it right

Any Idea ?

The HTML :

```
    <img src="/assets/img/PurchaseOrder.svg" />
    <svg class="menu-icon" width="150" height="150"  style="opacity: 1;"><use x="0"y="0"width="50" height="50" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/img/PurchaseOrder.svg#PurchaseOrder.svg"></use></svg>
    <svg class="menu-icon" width="150" height="150"  style="opacity: 1;"><use x="0"y="0"width="50" height="50" transform="scale(1,-1) translate(0,-50)" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/img/PurchaseOrder.svg#PurchaseOrder.svg"></use></svg>
```

The CSS

```
.menu-icon {
        pointer-events: none;
        fill:#626469;
    }
```

The result

[image]

The svg :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Calque_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="enable-background:new 0 0 24 24;" xml:space="preserve">
<symbol  id="ProjectOrder.svg" viewBox="-12 -12 24 24">
    . . .
</symbol>
<use xlink:href="#ProjectOrder.svg"  width="24" height="24" x="-12" y="-12" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 11.9995 11.9995)" style="overflow:visible;"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: It should be because you are setting the equivalent of `scaleY(-1)` through the matrix transform. If you don't need it, remove it.

Comment: I changed the matrix with 
matrix(1 0 0 1 12.0002 12) but the only change is the html <img> that is also reversed. should be elsewhere.

Comment: I played with illustrator changing upside down reverse sides, then exporting to SVG. 
The result is that the only diff is the matrix to flip coordinates.
What I suspect is that the illustrator and svg Y-axis are inverted.
When using the svg file inside a "use" tag, the embeded one might be overridden and then displayed with illustrator coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

replace the HTML with the following

```
<img src="/assets/img/PurchaseOrder.svg" />
    <svg class="menu-icon" width="150" height="150"  style="opacity: 1;"><use x="0"y="0"width="50" height="50" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/img/PurchaseOrder.svg#PurchaseOrder.svg"></use></svg>
    <svg class="menu-icon" width="150" height="150"  style="opacity: 1;"><use x="0"y="0"width="50" height="50" transform="translate(0,-50)" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/img/PurchaseOrder.svg#PurchaseOrder.svg"></use></svg>
```

what i did is remove the scale(1,-1) from the transform.

what you are doing with scale is basically flipping the Y axis with -1
thats why it is upside-down.

Comment: You are correct but I think the OP's problem is with the `transform = matrix(...)` in the SVG. Because that is already upside down, they are having to do a scale(1,-1) in the HTML. This is what I understood atleast.

Comment: @Harry It might be, if that is the case, why not just edit it with illustrator for example and re-save the svg. since it is made by his designer anyways.

Comment: Exactly. That's what I was thinking too.

Comment: @Harry, you'right the third exemple uses scale (1,-1) to display what i want. Saving the svg upside-down could be a workarroud indeed. But I should reverse it when using in HTML anyway.

Answer (score 0):

css property 
`transform: rotate(180deg);` will do flip.

Answer (score 0):

This looks as the same problem that I raised here:
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/76574/adobe-illustrator-svg-upside-down-transform-matrix.

Converting an object to a symbol in illustrator is messed up.
The object is placed inside the symbol upside-down. The symbol is then placed in the document upside-down, too, so the overall effect looks right.